# Cannot convert argument from wchar_t[260] to LPSTR

Tags: c++, windows, types

I'm trying to get the path of my executable on my windows machine.

```
    std::string get_exe_path_dir()
    {
        wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileName( NULL, path, MAX_PATH );
        PathRemoveFileSpec(path);
            
        std::wstring ws(path);
        std::string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
        return str.substr(0, str.find_last_of('/'));
    }
```

But now I get following error message:

cannot convert argument 2 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'LPSTR'

I tried casting but it didn't work.

Comment: `LPSTR` is a macro for `char*` so there's no way to cast a `wchar` to it. Nor should you try - Windows strings are Unicode, all applications are Unicode, NTFS filenames are Unicode. Why introduce bugs and arbitrary codepage conversions by using `char`? Don't use the ASCII functions or compile for ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using explicit `wchar_t` instead of `TCHAR`, so you should use explicit Unicode version `GetModuleFileNameW` and `PathRemoveFileSpecW` instead of `GetModuleFileName` and `PathRemoveFileSpec`.

Comment: `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` anyway, unless someone wants to explicitly create an application that fails due to codepage issues in 2021.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot didn't know there was a GetModuleFileNameW